# Open 4 fixed files in a tab in file browser via tasker

Tags: tasker

I have 4 file in a directory (path fixed). I want to open (and maybe edit as well) them like a tabbed file browser using tasker.
Is this possible?
For 4 files   A,B,C & D what I am looking for is:

```
 ____  ____  ____  ____
/_A__\/_b__\/_c__\/_d__\
|                       |
|Content of A when A    |
|is tabbed, and so for  |
|B,C,D                  |
|_______________________|
```

Kindly help

**Update**
While I am trying, with help from many videos, I have reached:

```
Scene: File browse
P:627x1154L:-1x-1
Element: Menu1/Menu
Geometry:
P:29,156 568x321 L:-1,-1 -1x-1
Content:
Source: Manual
Variable: %File_list
Selection Mode: None
Item Layout: Builtin Item Layout
Horizontal Space: 0
Vertical Space: 0
Events:
ItemClick: 31
Items:
1. Label: F1 Action: Open File [ File:Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u46826766/scratch/ToDo/Family.txt Mime Type: ]
2. Label: F2 Action: Open File [ File:Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u46826766/scratch/ToDo/WeekEnd.txt Mime Type: ]
```

but no idea about:
1) how to get a tabbed view
2) how to actually open the content of those file.

It currently looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02WblgE6NEvS292M1liRW1lS00/view?usp=sharing

Which is not at all what I am looking for.

Comment: What kind of files? What app do you want them to open in?

Comment: Those are plain text file,  i generally open them using  file manager  (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm&hl=en)